# Prevent sending data to DB/server if form validation is false (VueJS)

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, vue.js

I want to stop sending information if form validation is false. 
I have a button Save with two functions in it:

```
<span class="logInBTN" v-on:click="validationFields(); function2(model)">Save</span>
```

The form validation is being proccessed in `validationFields()`:

```
validationFields() {
  if (this.model.codePerson == '') {
    document.getElementById('codePerson').style.borderColor = "red";
    this.errors.push("Choose a type!\n");
    falseValidation = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('codePerson').style.borderColor = "#CCCCCC";
  }

  if (falseValidation == true) {
    alert("Form validation:\n" + this.errors.join(""));
  }
}
```

So if it's not chosen a type from the input field, `function2()` must not continue.

***Update1:***

```
<script>
    export default {
        components: {

        },
        data(){
            return {
                errors: [];
            },
        },
        methods: {
            validationFields() {

                this.errors = [];
                var falseValidation = false;

                if (this.model.codePerson == '') {
                    document.getElementById('codePerson').style.borderColor = "red";
                    this.errors.push("Choose a type!\n");
                    falseValidation = true;
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('codePerson').style.borderColor = "#CCCCCC";
                }

                if (falseValidation == true) {
                alert("Form validation:\n" + this.errors.join(""));
                }

                if(falseValidation == false){
                    this.createEori(eoriData);
                }
            }

            createEori(eoriData) {
                eoriData.state = '1';
                eoriData.username = this.$session.get('username');
                console.log("updateEori state: " + JSON.stringify(eoriData));
                const url = this.$session.get('apiUrl') + 'registerEORI';
                this.submit('post',
                    url,
                    eoriData
                );
            },

            submit(requestType, url, submitData) {
                this.$http[requestType](url, submitData)
                    .then(response => {
                    console.log('EORI saved!');
                console.log('Response:' + response.data.type);
                if("E" == response.data.type){
                    alert(response.data.errorDescription);
                    } else {
                        alert("Saved!");
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                console.log('EORI rejected!');
                console.log('error:' + error);
                });
            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

createEORI is the function2

***Update2***

Now it works, but the data from the fields it's not send to the server. That's all fields from the page, some are datepickers or an ordinary input text field. Before the change in the browser console show this, if I write a name in the first field it will show up in c1_name etc:

```
{"state":"1","c1_form":"","c1_identNumber":"","c1_name":"","c1_shortName":"","c1_8_street":"","c1_8_pk":"","c1_8_name":"","c1_8_city":"","c1_8_codeCountry":"","c1_identNumber1":"","c3_name":"","c3_nameShort":"","c3_city":"","c3_codeCountry":"","c3_street":"","c3_pk":"","c3_phone":"","codePerson":"","codeActivity":"","c1_date":"","c5_date":"","c7_date":"","dateFrom":"","dateTo":"","c8_date":"","c1_numberVAT":"","c8_provider":"","c8_number":"","codeMU":"","agreed1":"","agreed2":"","username":"testuser"}
```

However, after the change the sent data or at least the seen data is only:

```
{"state":"1","username":"testuser"}
```

The log is from

```
console.log("updateEori state: " + JSON.stringify(eoriData));
```

from createEORI() function

Comment: Why not remove the `function2()` call from the click handler and instead call it after your validation checks out?

Comment: `return false;` ? if the validation does not pass. But I think that @ChrisG suggestion is cleaner when it comes to click binding.

Comment: @ChrisG , you mean to make two buttons? One for validation and one for Saving?

Comment: @Decrux, I think what ChrisG says is that you will keep the single existing button with only `validationFields()` on click and then inside the `validationFields()` you call `function2(model)` when the validation is passed.

Comment: @Decrux No, not at all. Why not just call the send function from the validation function?

Comment: Give me a moment I will try it out and I will write what happened :)

Comment: Hmm, I am receiving Uncaught ReferenceError: function2() is not defined when I try to call it

Comment: @Decrux You need to call `this.function2(...)` live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/n9m4pv3vkp (check `components/HelloWorld`) You should also abandon stuff like manually changing the border color, that's not the Vue way.

Comment: @ChrisG this.function(model) - model is unresolved

Comment: @Decrux `this.function(this.model);`...? Show your code. (also, creating a Vue app while not knowing basic Vue techniques is going to cost you much more time than finishing whatever Vue courses you did or reading through the documentation and example code)

Comment: I updated my first post, function2() is createEORI

Comment: @ChrisG is the code enough? Or I did something wrong?

Comment: @Decrux When you call `this.createEori(eoriData);`, `eoriData` is undefined. It doesn't exist. Use `this.createEori();` instead, and in the `createEori` function, remove the parameter and add `var eoriData = {};` as first line. (note this is very basic javascript, how functions and variables work, and completely unrelated to Vue or server requests)

Comment: I updated again my first post and explained what happens now. I am not sure if its a problem, or just because of the change.

Comment: And I am not very sure why the information doesn't show up.

Comment: @ChrisG, the data now it's not sent. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed the problems with sending the data. 
It was my fault.

I will copy the Chris answer. That worked.

When you call `this.createEori(eoriData);`, eoriData is undefined. It doesn't exist. Use `this.createEori();` instead, and in the createEori function, remove the parameter and add var `eoriData = {};` as first line. (note this is very basic javascript, how functions and variables work, and completely unrelated to Vue or server requests)

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better practice to only call one function from the HTML. Something like this:

`<span class="logInBTN" v-on:click="submit(model)">Save</span>`

```
submit(model) {
    if (this.validateForm(model) == true)
    {
        // submission process here (maybe call function2())
    }
}

validateForm(model) {
    if (this.model.codePerson == ''){
        document.getElementById('codePerson').style.borderColor = "red";
        this.errors.push("Choose a type!\n");
        this.handleFalseValidation();
        return false;
    }

    document.getElementById('codePerson').style.borderColor = "#CCCCCC";
    return true;
}

handleFalseValidation() {
    alert("Form validation:\n" + this.errors.join(""));
}
```